# ¿Como validar correo electronico comerciales como gmail, hotmail, outlook, yahoo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla3

Basicamente tengo que validar un campo en un formulario que esta hecho en chronoforms una extensión de Joomla, muchos lo conocen.

El campo que deseo validar es el de "correo electronico", la validación consta de que el usuario no ingrese un correo "comercial" como hotmail, gmail, outlook, yahoo, live etc...

Ya que este formulario esta hecho en chronoform el script de validación se coloca dentro de esta función, no sé si la conozcan:

```
jQuery.fn.form.settings.rules.customfn = function(value, param) {  
return false;};
```

He averiguado como solucionar antes de realizar esta inquietud,viendo expresiones regulares y la verdad que no entiendo mucho.

Answer (score 1):

Hola encontré una solución básica y la misma solución esta dentro de la misma extensión

Es solo esto:

```
doesntContain[hotmail]: INGRESE UN CORREO VALIDO
doesntContain[gmail]: INGRESE UN CORREO VALIDO
doesntContain[outlook]: INGRESE UN CORREO VALIDO
doesntContain[live]: INGRESE UN CORREO VALIDO
doesntContain[yahoo]: INGRESE UN CORREO VALIDO
```

lo deben de colocar en "Validation rules" dentro del campo, existen más reglas aquí

https://www.chronoengine.com/forums/posts/t106813/validate-data-action-and-settings?keywords=